# Is it possible to change wx.Button's label text colour

Tags: wxpython, macos-catalina

[MacOS Catalina]

I'm a complete noob to wxPython.  I'm learning to use wxPython via a variety of online tutorials, but I'm having a bit of an issue I can't find an answer to.

Since I'm using 'Dark Mode' on my Mac, the label text of buttons is rendered white.  This makes them hard to read and I would prefer the text to be black.  However, I haven't been able to find anything that explains how to do this with a wx.button.  The closest answer I've been able to find suggests that it is possible to set System Options using something like `SetOptions(button_color=sg.COLOR_SYSTEM_DEFAULT)`, however I can't figure out what object to apply the setting to at the moment.

Is there a way of changing the colour of the `label` property of a `wx.button`?

My code is super simple:

```
  import wx

  class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
      def __init__(self):
          super(wx.Frame, self).__init__(parent=None, title='Hello World')
          panel = wx.Panel(self)

  #        wx.SetOptions(button_color=sg.COLOR_SYSTEM_DEFAULT)


          self.text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos=(5, 5))
          self.text_ctrl.SetBackgroundColour((255, 255, 255, 255))

          font = wx.Font(10, family = wx.FONTFAMILY_MODERN, style = 0, weight = 90,
                        underline = False, faceName ="", encoding = x.FONTENCODING_DEFAULT)
    
          my_btn = wx.Button(panel, label='Press Me', pos=(5, 55))
          my_btn.SetFont(font)
          my_btn.SetBackgroundColour((255, 0, 0, 255))
          my_btn.SetForegroundColour((255, 0, 0, 255))
  #        my_btn.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.RED))
  #        my_btn.AppendText("Red text\n")
  #        my_btn.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.NullColour, wx.LIGHT_GREY))
  #        my_btn.AppendText("Red on grey text\n")
  #        my_btn.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.BLUE))
  #        my_btn.AppendText("Blue on grey text\n")

          self.Show()

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      app = wx.App()
      frame = MyFrame()
      app.MainLoop()
```

The commented out lines indicate some of the things I've tried thus far.

**Edit**
The answer below works for Python3, but using Python2, I'm getting the following result:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried passing a `wx.Colour` object to `SetForegroundColour()` method? e.g.: `my_btn.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(255,0,0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SetOwnForegroundColour` of the button e.g.

```
import wx

class MainFream(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None,title='test',size=(500,500), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
        self.MainPanel = wx.Panel(self)

        test = []
        button_id = []
        for i in range(1,21):
            test.append(i)
            button_id.append(wx.NewId())

        self.button = []
        for i in range(len(test)):
            self.button.append(wx.Button(self.MainPanel,button_id[i],label=(str(test[i]))))
            self.button[i].Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)

        self.button[2].SetOwnForegroundColour(wx.RED)
        self.button[9].SetOwnForegroundColour(wx.GREEN)
        self.button[12].SetOwnForegroundColour("brown")
        self.button[16].SetOwnForegroundColour("cadetblue")

        sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(0, 5, 5, 5)
        for i in self.button:
            sizer.Add(i, 0, wx.ALL, 0)
        self.MainPanel.SetSizer(sizer)

    def OnButton(self, event):
        Id = event.GetId()
        Obj = event.GetEventObject()
        print ("Button Id",Id)
        print ("Button Pressed:",Obj.GetLabelText())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    fream = MainFream()
    fream.Show()

    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  This works with Python3, but doesn't produce the same result using Python2.

Comment: @gone Whoops! You don't say what happens with python2. There probably is a solution but I no longer keep python2 on my machine. I should probably add some more caveats, there may be differences in behaviour dependent on whether you use Gtk2 or Gtk3 and the behaviour may also depend on the `Theme` that you choose for your desktop. (StaticBox being a bugbear for me and the theme I prefer)